# Swagger validate says token does not exist despite the fact that it actually does exist

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm running the following command with `swagger-cli`:

```
swagger-cli validate src/swagger/swagger.yml
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
Token "Multiclassing" does not exist.
```

The files in question are:

**/src/swagger/schemas/combined.yml:**

```yaml
Multiclassing:
  $ref: './multiclassing.yml'
OptionSet:
  $ref: './common.yml#/option-set-model'
Option:
  $ref: './common.yml#/option-model'
```

**/src/swagger/schemas/multiclassing.yml**

```yaml
description: |
  `Multiclassing`
type: object
properties:
  prerequisites:
    description: List of prerequisites that must be met.
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: "./combined.yml#/Prerequisite"
  prerequisite_options:
    description: List of choices of prerequisites to meet for.
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: "./combined.yml#/Choice"
  proficiencies:
    description: "List of proficiencies available when multiclassing."
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: "./combined.yml#/APIReference"
  proficiency_choices:
    description: List of choices of proficiencies that are given when multiclassing.
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: "./combined.yml#/Choice"
```

**/src/swagger/schemas/classes.yml**

```yaml
class-model:
  description: |
    `Class`
  allOf:
    - $ref: './combined.yml#/APIReference'
    - type: object
      properties:
        hit_die:
          description: 'Hit die of the class. (ex: 12 == 1d12).'
          type: number
        class_levels:
          description: URL of the level resource for the class.
          type: string
        multi_classing:
          $ref: './combined.yml#/Multiclassing'
        spellcasting:
          $ref: './combined.yml#/Spellcasting'
        spells:
          description: URL of the spell resource list for the class.
          type: string
        starting_equipment:
          description: List of equipment and their quantities all players of the class start with.
          type: array
          items:
            type: object
            properties:
              quantity:
                type: number
              equipment:
                $ref: './combined.yml#/APIReference'
        starting_equipment_options:
          description: List of choices of starting equipment.
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: './combined.yml#/Choice'
        proficiency_choices:
          description: List of choices of starting proficiencies.
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: './combined.yml#/Choice'
        proficiencies:
          description: List of starting proficiencies for all new characters of this class.
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: './combined.yml#/APIReference'
        saving_throws:
          description: Saving throws the class is proficient in.
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: './combined.yml#/APIReference'
        subclasses:
          description: List of all possible subclasses this class can specialize in.
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: './combined.yml#/APIReference'
```

**/src/swagger/paths/classes.yml**

```yaml
class-multi-classing-path:
  get:
    summary: Get multiclassing resource for a class.
    tags:
      - Class
    parameters:
      - $ref: '../parameters/combined.yml#/class-index'
    responses:
      '200':
        description: OK
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '../schemas/combined.yml#/Multiclassing'
            example:
              prerequisites:
                - ability_score:
                    index: str
                    name: STR
                    url: '/api/ability-scores/str'
                  minimum_score: 13
              proficiencies:
                - index: shields
                  name: Shields
                  url: '/api/proficiencies/shields'
                - index: simple-weapons
                  name: Simple Weapons
                  url: '/api/proficiencies/simple-weapons'
                - index: martial-weapons
                  name: Martial Weapons
                  url: '/api/proficiencies/martial-weapons'
              proficiency_choices: []
```

I double and triple checked the paths that leads to Multiclassing in the 2 classes files and they seem to be correct. I reproduced the file paths so others can verify that the paths used in the snippets are correct. What's even stranger is that I only started seeing this issue after updating parts of the swagger docs that are completely unrelated to multiclassing.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

**Update:** I did some debugging and am even more confused.

Another file for context:
**/src/swagger/schemas/comman.yml**

```yaml
option-model:
  description: |
    `Option`
  oneOf:
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_type:
          description: 'Type of option; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        item:
          $ref: './combined.yml#/APIReference'
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_type:
          description: 'Type of option; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        action_name:
          description: 'The name of the action.'
          type: string
        count:
          description: 'The number of times this action can be repeated if chosen.'
          type: number
        type:
          description: 'For attack options that can be melee, ranged, abilities, or thrown.'
          type: string
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_type:
          description: 'Type of option; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        items:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: './combined.yml#/Option'
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_type:
          description: 'Type of option; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        choice:
          $ref: './combined.yml#/Choice'
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_type:
          description: 'Type of option; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        string:
          description: 'The string.'
          type: string
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_type:
          description: 'Type of option; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        desc:
          description: 'A description of the ideal.'
          type: string
        alignments:
          description: 'A list of alignments of those who might follow the ideal.'
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: './combined.yml#/APIReference'
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_type:
          description: 'Type of option; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        count:
          description: 'Count'
          type: number
        of:
          $ref: './combined.yml#/APIReference'
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_type:
          description: 'Type of option; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        ability_score:
          $ref: './combined.yml#/APIReference'
        minimum_score:
          description: 'The minimum score required to satisfy the prerequisite.'
          type: number
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_type:
          description: 'Type of option; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        ability_score:
          $ref: './combined.yml#/APIReference'
        bonus:
          description: 'The bonus being applied to the ability score'
          type: number
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_type:
          description: 'Type of option; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        name:
          description: 'Name of the breath'
          type: string
        dc:
          $ref: './combined.yml#/DC'
        damage:
          description: 'Damage dealt by the breath attack, if any.'
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: './combined.yml#/Damage'
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_type:
          description: 'Type of option; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        damage_type:
          $ref: './combined.yml#/APIReference'
        damage_dice:
          description: 'Damage expressed in dice (e.g. "13d6").'
          type: string
        notes:
          description: 'Information regarding the damage.'
          type: string
option-set-model:
  description: |
    `Option Set`
  oneOf:
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_set_type:
          description: 'Type of option set; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        options_array:
          description: 'Array of options to choose from.'
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: './combined.yml#/Option'
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_set_type:
          description: 'Type of option set; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        equipment_category:
          $ref: './combined.yml#/APIReference'
    - type: object
      properties:
        option_set_type:
          description: 'Type of option set; determines other attributes.'
          type: string
        resource_list:
          description: 'A reference (by URL) to a collection in the database.'
          type: string
choice-model:
  description: |
    `Choice`
  type: object
  properties:
    desc:
      description: 'Description of the choice to be made.'
      type: string
    choose:
      description: 'Number of items to pick from the list.'
      type: number
    type:
      description: 'Type of the resources to choose from.'
      type: string
    from:
      $ref: './combined.yml#/OptionSet'
```

Notice at the end that I set a property called `from` on `choice-model` that uses a ref. If the ref points to `OptionSet` or `Option` I get the error when I validate. If I use any other type it validates fine. As far as I can tell, this still has nothing to do with multiclassing.

Comment: What tool gives you that error?

Comment: @Helen swagger-cli gave me the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I added in the update to my post, I found the answer. I turns out swagger doesn't support circular references. The `from` in choice references `OptionSet`, which references `Option`, which in turn references both `Choice` and `Option` again. When I removed the circular reference I stopped getting the error.

With all of that said, none of this has to do with multiclassing. I suppose the moral of the story is that `swagger-cli` lies sometimes.